# ISO Week vs SQL Server Week

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Okay so I have a report that does a this week vs last week comparison and our customer noticed that their data was "funky". Upon further investigation we found it was not doing weeks correctly according to the ISO standards. I ran this script as a test case.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '3/26/13')
    , DATEPART(WEEK, '3/27/12')
    , DATEPART(WEEK, '3/20/12')
    , DATEPART(WEEK, '1/2/12')
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '3/26/13')
    , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '3/27/12')
    , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '3/20/12')
    , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '1/2/12')
```

When run I got these results.

[image: ResultSet]

I thought this was peculiar and so I did some more digging and found that SQL Server counts January 1st as the first week of the year where ISO counts the first Sunday in January as the first week of the year.

The question then ends up being two fold. Question 1 why is this? Question 2 is there any way to change this so I'm not having to modify all of my code to use `ISO_Week` everywhere?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Back when SQL Server first implemented the `WEEK` date/part, they had to make a choice. I don't think there was really much consciousness about it, except to align to the most common standard at the time - remember this was at a time where conforming to the standards was not a top priority (else we'd not have things like `timestamp`, `IDENTITY` and `TOP`). They later added `ISO_WEEK` (2008 I believe) because the workaround in the meantime was to write your own, slow, crappy scalar UDF - in fact they even created a really bad one and put it in the official documentation (it has since been removed as far as I can tell).

I don't know of a way to make `DATEPART(WEEK` pretend it is `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK` - I think you will have to change the code (and if you are using source control, this shouldn't be very hard - how many places are you performing this calculation? Have you thought about computing it somewhere so your code doesn't have to be riddled with it? Since you're changing the code now, this might be the time to consider this...).

And if you really want the answer to *why?* I think you'll have to grab some of the original developers to determine why they chose the default that they did. Again, I think it wasn't an actual "F the standards!" choice, but rather, "What standards?"

There is some information here that may be useful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348880/getting-week-number-off-a-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/iso-week-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

There are several authorities assuming different conditions for the first week of the year.
Some assumes first day of the week starts the first week but the most common idea is that the first week which has the first Thursday is the first week of the year.

So `ISO_WEEK` accepts that and like in 2010, 2011 or 2012 as you can check that `ISO_WEEK` says 1st January is 52nd or 53rd week while `WEEK` or `WK` or `WW` says they are the first week.

```
SELECT DATEPART (WW,'01/01/2010')   --> 1
SELECT DATEPART (WK,'01/01/2010')   --> 1
SELECT DATEPART (WEEK,'01/01/2010')   --> 1
SELECT DATEPART (ISO_WEEK,'01/01/2010')   --> 53
```